# Avoid page break between poemtitle and poem

Tags: page-breaking, windows, poetry, poemscol

### Explanations

The `\poemtitle` command and `poem` environment (both from [`poemscol`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/poemscol)) occur page break when it happens at the end of the page. So it look like an ugly widow.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}

\begin{document}

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

\poemtitle{Foo}
\begin{poem}
lorem\\
ipsum\\
dolor\\
sit\\
amet\\
et\\
consectetur
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

### Rendering

[image: Rendering of the poemtitle troubleshouting]

As you see, the title “Foo” appears at bottom of page, followed by the poem.

### My tries

#### Try 1: redefine the command `\poemtitle`

I add in the preamable this redefinition of `\poemtitle` (I take the original one from the package)

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\poemtitle}[1]{\nobreak%
\set@p@emtitle{#1}{\poemtitlepenalty}{\poemtitlefont}%
{\relax}{\nobreak\par\nobreak\afterpoemtitleskip\nobreak}{\z@}%
\c@ntentsinfo{#1}{\contentsindentone}{\contentspoemtitlefont}%
{\contentsindenttwoamount}\nobreak%
\t@xtnotesinfo{#1}\nobreak%
}
\makeatother
```

But it haven’t any effect.

#### Try 2: Changing the `\poemtitlepenalty` value

The package mention `\newcommand{\poemtitlepenalty}{\penalty-1000}`

So, I redifine the command with, as value `\penalty-4000`, `\penalty-300`, `\penalty-20`, `\penalty+1000`, to see if it change something, but it change nothing.

#### Try 3: Redefining the `poem` environment

I redefine the `poem` environment to it most minimalist form:

```
\renewenvironment{poem}[1][\linewidth]
{\nobreak%
     \nobreak\begin{pmclverse}[#1]\nobreak%
     }{\end{pmclverse}%
     }
```

But it didn’t affect the rendering.

#### Try 4: Redefining the `pmclverse` environment

In `poemscol` the `poem` environment call the `pmclverse` one. So, I also redefine it. I comment lot of thing and I put `\nobreak` everywhere in vain :

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{pmclverse}[1][\linewidth]{%
%\let\\=\@centercr%
\nobreak\list{}{\itemsep\z@
%\itemindent -\runoverindentvalue
\nobreak\listparindent \itemindent
%        \ifdim #1 < \linewidth
%           \rightmargin        \z@
%           \setlength{\leftmargin}{\linewidth}%
%           \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-#1}%
%           \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\leftmargin}%
%         \else
%           \rightmargin        \leftmargin
%         \fi
%\advance\leftmargin\runoverindentvalue
}
\nobreak\item[]\nobreak}
{\endlist}
\makeatother
```

#### Summary of tries

Certainly, I combine all this tries in one, and it doesn’t have any effect on the page break.

### Conclusion

Finally just forbid pagebreak betwen `\poemtitle` and `poem` environment?

Comment: You can add locally `\clearpage` just before `\poemtitle`.

Comment: this package as a number of errors. It uses fancyhdr commands but doesn't load the package, it uses \makeatletter/\makeatother and so breaks biblatex, it claims that it tests if there is enough place for the title and the poem but doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using `needspace` package? Your MWE works for me if I add this package and create an environment `mypoem` to which I demand that it reserve some space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}

\usepackage{needspace}
\newenvironment{mypoem}[1]%   #1 = Title
{%
  \needspace{3\baselineskip}% <-- We need at least 3 more lines before...
  \poemtitle{#1}
  \begin{poem}
}
{\end{poem}}

\begin{document}

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa\\aa

\begin{mypoem}{Foo}
lorem\\
ipsum\\
dolor\\
sit\\
amet\\
et\\
consectetur
\end{mypoem}
\end{document}
```

[image]